# How to assign value to argument column name?

Tags: postgresql

Here, we are trying to create common trigger function to all tables. we have to try pass an argument as column name(primary key column in table) to get the max value of that column in all tables. here the problem is we got the max of value of argument column but we can't assign the value to that argument column name.

```
declare 
    ll_maxid integer;
    arg_column text :=TG_ARGV[0]::text;
begin

    if TG_WHEN ='BEFORE' AND TG_OP='INSERT' THEN
        
        execute format('SELECT coalesce(max(%s),0)+1 FROM %I.%I',arg_column,TG_TABLE_SCHEMA, TG_TABLE_NAME) INTO ll_maxid;
        
        new.arg_column := ll_maxid;
        
    end if;
    return new;
    
end;
```

**Error  - The record new has no field 'arg_column'**

how can I achieve this. I use PostgreSQL 13.2

Comment: It seems you already know how to `execute` dynamic sql… why not use it for assigning as well?

Comment: Not enough information. Need 1) Trigger definition. 2) Definition of the table that the trigger is attached to.  3) Explanation of what you are trying to accomplish? **Add information as update to question**. Also if you are indeed using Postgres 9.4 it is ~2.5 years past EOL and you should upgrade. If you are not remove the postgresql-9.4 tag. The error is occurring because the table that the trigger is attached to has no column named *arg_column*.

Comment: Also should this `... max(%s) ...` not be `...max(%I)...`? The value of `arg_column` is I assume a column name and therefore an identifier not a simple string.

Comment: @Bergi Hi Sir, I have already tried what you say. But same error occurs. please confirm , is that possible?

Comment: @AdrianKlaver Hi sir, I have used %s used for string argument and %I for schema and table name. the actual issue is  I got the column name perfectly and max value of that column. but I can't assign the value of that argument. Please confirm ,is that Possible ?

Comment: @manaz Please [edit] your question to show the code that you've tried

Answer (score 0):

I have yet to find a way to modify `NEW` in this manner in `plpgsql`. I can do it using `plpython3u`:

```
create table new_col_table (id integer, fld_1 integer, max_fld integer)

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.new_col()
 RETURNS trigger
 LANGUAGE plpython3u
AS $function$

    arg_column = TD['args'][0]

    if TD['when'] == 'BEFORE' and TD['event'] =='INSERT':
    
        plpy.notice("Value is " + arg_column)
        rs = plpy.execute("select coalesce(max(fld_1), 0) as max_val from " + TD["table_schema"] + "." + TD["table_name"])
        TD['new'][arg_column] = rs[0]['max_val']
    return "MODIFY";

$function$
;

create trigger new_col_trg before insert on new_col_table for each row execute function new_col(max_fld);

insert into new_col_table values (1, 3, 3);
NOTICE:  Value is max_fld
INSERT 0 1
insert into new_col_table values (2, 3, 0);
NOTICE:  Value is max_fld
INSERT 0 1

select * from new_col_table ;
 id | fld_1 | max_fld 
----+-------+---------
  1 |     3 |       0
  2 |     3 |       3

select * from new_col_table ;
```